# Bookshelf.js relation with foreign key from a property in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, bookshelf.js

I have 2 models

- `Book: id, name, data (json)`
- `Author: id, name`

I want to extend `Book` model with method `author` which return the author when query `withRelated`. This could be easy to achieve with below snippet, provided that I have `author_id` in `Book`

```js
const Book = bookshelf.model('Book', {
  tableName: 'books',
  author() {
    return this.belongsTo('Author', 'author_id', 'id')
  }
})
```

But the problem is, `author_id` is a property of `data` (which is json type). I tried the snippet below but it not worked

```js
const Book = bookshelf.model('Book', {
  tableName: 'books',
  author() {
    return this.belongsTo('Author', `data->>'author_id'`, 'id')
  }
})
```

If I am not allowed to have any changes in the origin models, how could I get `author` in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that the type of Author.id is integer. `data->>'author_id'` is text. Try `(data->>'author_id')::integer` i.e. cast to integer.

Comment: id here is `uuid` type, so text would be okay

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a solution that worked, a little bit tricky combination of `related` and event hook

```js
const Book = bookshelf.model('Book', {
  tableName: 'books',
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('fetched', async function(model) {
      model.set('author_id', (model.get('data') || {}).author_id || null)
      const author = await model.related('author').fetch()
      model.set('author', author)
    })
  },
  author() {
    return this.belongsTo('Author')
  }
})
```